# Keep still playing Audiograph UWP output when minimized or locked

Tags: windows-10, uwp

It's really easy to configure audio with audiograph classes but when I minimize or lock the screen the audio pauses. Does any solve how to keep the audio playing when is minimized?

In my case I use even more than 10 mp3s files playing at the same time with multiple effects that changes all the time. The only way might be sending the output to a stream and get that with the background media of the background task but I haven't done nothing similar to know if it could work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only need an AudioGraph and not the MediaPlayer, you can actually run an AudioGraph in the background task of a BackgroundMediaPlayer without connecting it to the MediaPlayer.

I took the [background audio sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/BackgroundAudio/cs) and my audio graph runs fine even when the foreground is suspended! The BackgroundMediaPlayer keeps the background task alive, and as a bonus you can use the `SendMessageToForeground/Background` methods to communicate with the main app.

Comment: Thanks, I was very busy with other projects and I thought about that but no time. The other background task project can read mp3s from the main project? with that I can mark it as answer.

Comment: How did you run the background task winrt from the App? I tested new AudioBackgroundTask().Run(null); and plays Audiograph but when I minimize the window the sound stops

Comment: It was easier than that, just invoking something about the bgmediaplayer and begins the Run method, thanks and now happy new year now I can finish my app!!

Comment: Excellent to hear! You can't send StorageFile objects directly to the background task, so you'll have to send a Uri and open the StorageFile in the background. If these MP3s are contained within your application you should be fine, otherwise you might need to use the `Windows.Storage.AccessCache.StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList` and pass a token to the background.

Comment: Well in desktop works fine, but in mobile it stops, but I will take a look next year :).

Answer (score -1):

There should be two solutions:

1. Using BackgroundMediaPlayer, you can find [sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/browse/) and [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/apps/hh202978%28v=vs.105%29) on MSDN. Since BackgroundMediaPlayercan can only play files from isolated storage or from a remote URI, you can firstly utilize AudioFileOutputNode by saving the audiograph processed audio content to a file, then load the file to an isolated storage for BackgroundMediaPlayer;
2. You can also utilize [ExtendedExecutionSession](https://dailydotnettips.com/using-extended-execution-in-windows-10-universal-apps/), which means you can send a request to operating system to extend the time frame to complete the pending task before Operating system terminate the app. Of course, this is not really a background task, because it is intended to buy you a bit of extra time to do extra work when moving to a new power state.

Comment: I have tested the second option and does not work with AudioGraph, about the first I use about 10 sounds playing at the same time with several effects applying and it changes so is not an static audio file, might be is possible